# Would the barycenter in a binary star system be ideal for a space habitat?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I was reading about [binary star systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star) and saw a bunch of diagrams, mainly the following:

[image]

Would there be benefits to creating a space station in the center of two binary rotating bodies? Would it be a completely stationary satellite in terms relative to that of the local binary system? What would be better/worse about it comparative to an orbital space station if anything?

Comment: Completely unstable. If you lose your ability to actively maintain your position, you will fall right into one of the stars.

Comment: I agree it's unstable, but saddle-point unstable, something like L1 and L2. Both stars will have deep potential wells, and near either one the potential field of that star will dominate. An object drifting off the barycenter at low speed will have little or no angular momentum with respect to the barycenter, but loads of angular momentum with respect to either star. If the initial drift is very slow it might take several stellar revolutions before the object "chooses" one or the other star, but then would make a high-*e* orbit of that star and then go essentially chaotic, probably eject.

Comment: @TomSpilker - The barycenter is only saddle-point stable if the two stars have exactly the same mass. Otherwise, it's unstable, period. The habitat will fall straight toward the more massive star.

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree, saddle-point stable only if the masses are the same. And the *initial* acceleration would indeed be directly toward the more massive star. And in a *rotating* reference frame, as the object moves from the barycenter, the Coriolis OmegaX(OmegaX*R*) term gets larger so that component of acceleration increases. But as soon as the object's velocity is non-zero the 2(OmegaX*V*) term goes non-zero as well, deflecting the motion from directly toward the star. I *think* it will be a complex trajectory, not straight toward the star. I have calculations to do!

Comment: Tom Spilker I believe you're confusing barycenter with L1. Barycenter will be closer to the more massive star. Possibly even on or below the more massive star's surface. L1 will be closer to the less massive star.

Comment: @DavidHammen I wrote an orbit integrator to handle this. If the object's initial velocity is small (smaller than escape velocity from the larger star, at the object's initial position at the barycenter) the object doesn't collide with the larger star unless the stars are close enough that the barycenter is only a few (less than ~3-4, depending on *Vo*) stellar radii from the larger. Instead it enters an orbit around the larger star, one whose eccentricity varies a lot with time as a result of 3rd-body forces from the smaller star.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The net gravitational acceleration of a small test mass located at some point $\boldsymbol x_p$ toward the two stars is
$$
\boldsymbol a_{\boldsymbol p;\text{net}} = G m_1
\frac{\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_p}
{||\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_p||^3} +
G m_2
\frac{\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol x_p}
{||\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol x_p||^3}
$$
where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the two stars and $\boldsymbol x_1$ and $\boldsymbol x_2$ are the positions of the two stars in that inertial frame.

The barycenter $\boldsymbol x_b$ satisfies
$$
m_1 (\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b) +
m_2 (\boldsymbol x_2 - \boldsymbol x_b) = \boldsymbol 0$$
The net acceleration at the barycenter is thus
$$\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol a_{\boldsymbol b;\text{net}} &= G m_1
\frac{\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b}
{||\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b||^3} -
G m_2
\frac{\frac{m_1}{m_2}(\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b)}
{\left(\frac{m_1}{m_2}\right)^3||\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b||^3} \\
&= G m_1
\frac{\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b}
{||\boldsymbol x_1 - \boldsymbol x_b||^3}
\left(1 - \left(\frac{m_2}{m_1}\right)^3\right)
\end{aligned}$$
A habitat located at the barycenter will thus accelerate toward whichever star is more massive. The acceleration will be zero only if the two stars have exactly the same mass. The probability of this happening is essentially zero. Even if you did manage to find a binary pair that have exactly the same mass, the probability that the habitat can be placed exactly at the barycenter and moving with the barycenter is essentially zero.

In short, placing a habitat at the barycenter is a bad idea.

Comment: That's true. On the other hand there is a  Lagrange point on the line between the two stars which is only saddle-point unstable.

Comment: @SteveLinton - I thought about addressing that issue, but decided against doing so. As you mentioned, that point is unstable, as are pseudo orbits about it. Fuel is needed to maintain such pseudo orbits. A lot more fuel is needed to stay at (in practice, stay close to) the L1 point.

Comment: @David Hammen, does your model allow you to aproximate the DV costs of arriving/departing a barcentric station? Suspecting this might be an expensive place to visit.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - Multiplying the acceleration by some span of time yields the delta V needed to stay at the barycenter for that spat of time.

Comment: @David Hammen, was thinking about travel from a planet/asteroid belt orbiting the barycentre outside the pair into the point and stopping (vs the cost to a more conventional orbiting station). Noodling with universe sandbox suggested brute force approach, effectively doing a hohman transfer to orbital speed 0 is expensive, but options exist to exploit the instability to make cheaper transits if you have more time and computing power.